# Is the speed of light the same in a true vacuum and a false vacuum?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, speed-of-light, vacuum

Is there a difference in the speed of light in a true vacuum vs. a false vacuum?

Comment: What do you mean by "a false vacuum"?  Is there a particular model involving a false vacuum that you have in mind?

Answer (score 3):

First, just to be clear, the *speed of light* is a misnomer in the context of relativity. We should distinguish between:

- The speed of massless particles (or, equivalently, the maximum speed of causal influences)
- The speed at which photons travel.

The reason I'm making this distinction is because a change in the vacuum state could lead to a change in the mass of the photon; however I take it this is *not* what you are interested in. Therefore, for the rest of this answer, I'll use "the speed of light" in the first sense.

Because the speed of light is a dimensionful variable, we can *always* choose our system of units so that it takes a given value (say, $1$). By performing a coordinate transformation to a locally inertial coordinate system, we can always arrange that light travels at $c$ in the neighborhood of any event.

The only *physical* quantities that are unambiguous and agreed upon by all observers are *dimensionless quantities*, like the fine structure constant. Dimensionless quantities absolutely can change as a result of false vacuum decay, if they are associated with background fields that change during the vacuum transition.$^\dagger$

---

$^\dagger$ Although, to be 100% clear, there is no experimental evidence suggesting that the value of the fine structure constant is associated with a field; it is a logical possibility given the rules of QFT but it's also logically possible that vacuum decay does not happen in our Universe or that the fine structure constant does not change.